# Riesz potential on the boundary of a smooth domain

Tags: harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces, potential-theory

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a measurable set of finite measure. It
is well-known that there holds
$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\Omega} \frac{d z}{| x - z |^{n - 1}}
   \leqslant c_n | \Omega |^{1 / n} $$
where $c_n$ is a positive constant depending only on $n$.

Now, let $\Omega$
be a smooth and bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Does anyone know where I can find
``similar'' estimates (upper bounds) for the function
$$
x \in \Omega \mapsto \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{d z}{| x - z |^{n - 1}}
$$
in terms (I suppose) of the distance of $x$ from the boundary of $\partial
\Omega$?

Comment: OK. I was to quick to answer your question.  If I find time I will answer it. Right now I am deleting my answer.

Comment: It diverges like the logaritm of the distance from the boundary.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune thanks Giorgio, that sounds very plausible. Can you refer me to more details?

Comment: Yes, sure. Let $t$ be the distance of $x$ to the boundary and split $\partial \Omega=\cup E_k$, $E_k=\{z: 2^k t \leq |x-z| <2^{k+1} t\}$. If $D$ is the diameter of $\Omega$, then $E_k$ is empty if $2^k t>D$. Each $E_k$ is contained in a geodesic ball of radius proportional to $2^{k+1}t$ and its measure is bounded by $C2^{(k+1)(n-1)}t^{n-1}$ (here the geometry of $\partial \Omega$ enters to make things quantitative). Now write the integral as $\sum_k\int_{E_k}$, each $\int_{E_k}$ is bounded by an absolute constant and there are $\approx \log (1/t)$ terms in the sum.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune It is clear the idea you have in mind and seems a smart approach. I will try to fill in the details. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune, I've tried to work out the details and I am puzzled by the special choice of the set $E_k$ involving $2^k$ and $2^{(k+1)}$ instead of, e.g., $k$ and $k+1$. I understood that the result you quote: Each $E_k$ is contained in a geodesic ball of radius proportional to... is where all the difficulties are hidden. I would really (really) appreciate it if you could give me a reference for that result. I was trying to find it by myself but could not look it up (just got the feeling that I had to look for results on comparison theorems). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me try in this way. Consider a (euclidean) ball $B(x,r)$ and $y \in \partial \Omega \cap B(x,r)$. Then $B(x,r) \subset B(y, 2r)$. If $x_n=\psi(x')$ is a local parametrization and $P=(x', \psi(x'))$, $Q=(z', \psi(z'))$, then $|x'-y'| \leq |P-Q| \leq c |x'-y'|$. This means than, in local coordinates, $B(y,2r)\cap \partial \Omega$ is described by a set of diameter less than $4r$ and then has $(n-1)$ volume less than $Cr^{n-1}$. This avoids the use of geodesic balls. However requires local coordinates and I wonder how explicit one can make $C$.

Comment: Thanks Giorgio. I will go through your suggestion. Most likely I will write you again. That said, I was really interested in the approach based on the geodesic balls. And I would really appreciate it if you could give me a more or less precise reference where I can find or collect results that bring to the equivalences you were quoting (that really depend on the choice of $2^k$ and $2^(k+1)$).

Comment: Please, quote my name if you write to me, I noticed your last message just by chance.  I do not know a reference but should be where people prove that open set with smooth boundary are "homogeneuous spaces". I knew that the answer was vague though reasonable. When  I saw your question I first did the computation for a flast boundary. By the way, the proof works also with $k$ instead of $2^k$: write the new $E_k=F_k\setminus F_{k-1}$ and use summation by parts.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune yes your idea works also with $k$ and $k+1$. But then you don't have anymore uniform lower bounds and upper bounds independent from $k$ (I am vague but if you redid the computation you understand what I mean). In some sense it is the $2^k$ that make a small miracle allowing to treat all the terms of the sums as the same constant. That's why I am puzzled. You have to know something about that choice of $2^k$ which is a very educated choice. I will look for the type of results you suggest. I am really interested into grasping the idea not just at the formal level. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using my previous comment on Euclidean balls, it is sufficient to compare geodesic balls with euclidean one, that is the Riemannian metric $\delta$  on $\partial \Omega$ with the euclidean one $d$. But this are equivaent, that is $d \leq \delta \leq cd$ for some $c$ depending on $\partial \Omega$. This I see again in local coordinates...but $c$ is something....